# PyWin32 Print: Specify Number of copies

Tags: python, pywin32

I was building a function to print PDF files from a folder, and I need to specify the number of copies, actually I was doing by doing a loop with the number of copies and run the function into it. But the printing pool saturates when the number of copies is high, logically, it generates a single document to print for every copy instead of group the prints into one document with X number of copies.

Here is the the code I use with win32print to print a single document once.
Anyone know the argument or the option to tell the function the number of copies?

Thanks!

```
from os import path
import win32print
from win32com import client
import time
import win32api
import pywintypes
name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter() # verify that it matches with the name of your printer
printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} # Doesn't work with PRINTER_ACCESS_USE
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name, printdefaults)
level = 2
attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)
#attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 1  #no flip
#attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 2  #flip up
attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 3   #flip over
win32print.SetPrinter(handle, level, attributes, 0)
win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)['pDevMode'].Duplex
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print','manual1.pdf','.','/manualstoprint',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of using Sumatra PDF? Most command line PDF options can be pretty limited (such as in this case), but there's an option in Sumatra's commands to specify copies like so (the 3x implies 3 copies):

```
SumatraPDF -print-to-default -silent -exit-on-print -print-settings "3x" "[document location]"
```

Of course, to do this you'll need to make a subprocess call from python instead of using win32api. More info on the Sumatra command line [here.](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments.html)

Comment: I don't want to use any other PDF applications ahead of the OS integrated, that's why I use win32print.
That's because the full program that contains this function is very large and I don't want make the user install other programs to do basic functions.
So I need to know if there's an option in Win32Print to do that.

Comment: In that case your options might be limited I'm afraid, I don't believe win32print has that functionality. If your main concern is too many print jobs saturating the pool, you could try using PyPDF2 to merge multiple copies of the same document into one larger PDF file, then sending that as a single print job.

Comment: I will take a look at the documentation of PyPDF, this could solve my problem, not the way I like to do, but anyway work. Thanks.